# Process in 1D, conclusions from gap distributions

Tags: stochastic-processes

preface: *sorry if I am using the wrong nomenclature, part of my problem is that I don't know enough to google what I am looking for.*

Let's say I have a large sorted set (or an ensemble of sets) of events $x_i$ and I know that the "gaps" $\Delta = x_i-x_{i-1}$ are distributed in a way that $P(\Delta)\sim \Delta^\alpha$ for $\Delta \ll 1$. Is there anything to learn from just knowing $\alpha$? Or are there bounds to which values $\alpha$ can have under certain typical assumptions?

The process as a whole should be stationary, by which I mean that there is no explicit dependence on time.

The only thing I can come up with is that for $\alpha>0$ the events are repulsive in some sense whereas for $\alpha<0$ they are attractive. $\alpha=0$ should include the standard Poisson-process and correspond to independent events.

Comment: if the "events" are eigenvalues of a random matrix, then $\alpha$ will generically take on one of the three values $1,2,4$.

Comment: Thanks @CarloBeenakker , yeah I remember that. They are not directly, but maybe related? Say I have a pos-def matrix and am updating it randomly (in some fashion) and everytime the lowest eigenvalue crosses zero there is some renewal event (an instability in the system). Is there any statement about the zero-crossings?

Comment: all of this will depend on the type of process you are considering; a study of the spacing distribution of zero-crossings in a particular physics context is given in https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.2924